# Using jQuery, what selector do I use to get the last thead tr for each matching table?

Tags: jquery

On a single page, I have two tables. Each of them has a class of "data". Each of them has theads.

I want to apply formatting to the last row in *each* of the table's theads.

I originally had this:

```
$('table.data thead tr:last').children().addClass('col');
```

Which works fine if there is only one table on the page. But if there are multiple tables, that tr:last selector picks up the last tr for ALL of the tables matching the class, not EACH table.

How do I constrain this to operate on the last tr for each thead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`:last-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) instead to get the one in *each* `<thead>`, like this:

```
$('table.data thead tr:last-child').children().addClass('col');
//or possibly:
$('table.data thead tr:last-child > td').addClass('col');
```